# C# console application - Calculating an average number

Tags: c#, console-application

I tried to create a program which would give me an average score of 5 tests. First I created 5 variables that would be declared by an user. But I have a problem that I could not fix by myself. The output of my code shows a false average score of tests, probably I have a mistake somewhere and I would like you to help me in finding it. 
Here is a full code:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class MathTest
    {
        static void Main()  
        {
            string a, b, c, d, e;

            Console.WriteLine("1st Test Score: ");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("2nd Test Score: ");
            b = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("3rd Test Score: ");
            c = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("4th Test Score: ");
            d = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("5th Test Score: ");
            e = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your Average Test Score is: {0}", 
                               Convert.ToInt32(a + b + c + d + e) / 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully there is only one mistake in the last sentence, the formula. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You're adding strings together here so "1" + "3" + "5" will become "135".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `Convert.ToInt32` *each* item (`a`..`e`):

```
   ...
   Console.WriteLine("Your Average Test Score is: {0}", 
     (Convert.ToInt32(a) + 
      Convert.ToInt32(b) + 
      Convert.ToInt32(c) + 
      Convert.ToInt32(d) + 
      Convert.ToInt32(e)) / 5.0);
```

Another (possible) problem is *integer division*: if you want to have floating point result (e.g. average score `3.5`) you should divide by `5.0`, not `5`

Answer (score 2):

As others have correctly said, you need to convert the strings to numbers *first*, then add them, and then divide them.

That fixes some of your problems. However, not all your problems are over yet.

Next: what if someone types in a score of 75.5 ?  Teachers sometimes give half points. Integer is not the correct data type.  In C#, use *decimal* for quantities that are exact decimal quantities, and *double* for quantities that are physical amounts, like length or mass.  You should convert all the strings to *decimal*, not *int*.

Next: what if someone types in "Hello" or nothing at all, instead of a number?  Your program will crash. You need to use a method such as `TryParse` that detects this situation, and then you need to prompt the user accordingly to re-enter the number correctly.

Now, you should not be rewriting all that code five times over. **Make a method which prompts the user in a loop to enter a number, and returns that number when they do so successfully.**  Always be breaking your problem down into smaller problems and then write a method which solves that problem. That way your main routine stays simple even when your program logic gets complicated.

Finally and **most important**:  today is a good day to learn how to use a debugger.  Learn how to find problems like this on your own, rather than asking strangers on the internet to do your work for you.  **Most of computer programming is debugging**, so learn that skill **now**.

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating strings first, then casting the result to Int and dividing by 5.

Cast every number first, before doing maths on them.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the concatenated string. Suppose the user enters:
1
2
3
4
5
Then (a+b+c+d+e) is "12345" and you are calculating 12345/5. You need to cast all strings separately first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert before you Sum up.

```
Console.WriteLine("Your Average Test Score is: {0}", (Convert.ToInt32(a) + Convert.ToInt32(b) + Convert.ToInt32(c) + Convert.ToInt32(d) + Convert.ToInt32(e)/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out my mistake in the comments and answers and fixed the code (Changed only a mid part)

```
            int a, b, c, d, e;
        Console.WriteLine("1st Test Score: ");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("2nd Test Score: ");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("3rd Test Score: ");
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("4th Test Score: ");
        d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("5th Test Score: ");
        e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Your Average Test Score is: {0}", Convert.ToInt32(a + b + c + d + e) / 5.0);
```